# fail send html email by using php

Tags: php, html, email

I have problem when i try to send html email by using mail() on php , when i try to using this code it`s working perfect

```
        $bodyhtml="<html>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>

<div dir='RTL'> 
    <p dir='RTL'>      
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <td> 
                    <div>  
                        <p dir='RTL'><strong><span style='color:#00B0F0'>Hi</span></strong></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><strong><span style='color:#FFC000'>Test</span></strong></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><span style='color:#404040'>Test</span></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><span style='color:#404040'>Test</span></p>  </div></td> </tr> </table>       
                        </p>    
                        </div> </body></html>";
        $headers = "From: " . $email. "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: me@gmail.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        mail($email, $subject, $bodyhtml, $headers);
```

but when i try to put image with html massage :

```
        $bodyhtml="<html>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>

<div dir='RTL'> 
    <p dir='RTL'>                      </p> 
    <p dir='RTL'>      
        <table> 
            <tr> 
            <img src='http://xxxxxx/form/image/image001.png' />
                <td> 
                    <div>  
                        <p dir='RTL'><strong><span style='color:#00B0F0'>Hi</span></strong></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><strong><span style='color:#FFC000'>Test</span></strong></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><span style='color:#404040'>Test</span></p> 
                        <p dir='RTL'><span style='color:#404040'>Test</span></p>  </div></td> </tr> </table>         </p>        </div> </body></html>";
        $headers = "From: " . $email. "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: technomedia.ws@gmail.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        mail($email, $subject, $bodyhtml, $headers);
```

it fails when send massage , what's the problem or how I can solve that?

Comment: It might help if you post the code that is NOT working instead of code that is working

Comment: Try placing the `<img>` within the `<td>`, if you mess up tables strange things can happen

Comment: Also make sure you have error reporting on, an actual error message might be helpful as well

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ok , i`m editing my post

Comment: @GeraldSchneider when i try to put <img> within the <td> it also fail , how i can read the report ? there`s no error_log on my space

Comment: `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` turns on error reporting.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider there is no any error showing .but did not send mail

Answer (score 0):

Just read in php doc :

> Finally, if you add an image and want it displayed in your email,
>   change the Content-Type from attachment to inline:

```
$message .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$theFile\"\n\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php

EDIT : Your solution is probably here -> http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

Comment: This is only nessecary for images sent within the email, not for images linked from external sources

Answer (score -1):

Try using `img` tag correctly:

```
<img src='http://xxx/form/image/image001.png' />
```